# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resize buffer - 315 bytes have already been written (Servlet 2.3, sec. 5.1)

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic-10.x, java-ee-5

My web application use Weblogic 10.3.6, Javaee 5 and authentication by LDAP.
After authentication success my filter try to execute `chain.doFilter(request, response);`
And throws this exception

```
    ####<Sep 25, 2015 11:34:54 AM BRT> <Error> <HTTP> <viniciusbrito-Vostro-230> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1443191694402> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@1836230698[app:frente-loja-web module:frente-loja-web.war path:/frente-loja-web spec-version:2.5]] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resize buffer - 315 bytes have already been written (Servlet 2.3, sec. 5.1)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.setBufferSize(ServletResponseImpl.java:357)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.initialize(PageContextImpl.java:74)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.<init>(PageContextImpl.java:110)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspFactoryImpl.getPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at jsp_servlet.__index._jspService(__index.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at br.com.pernambucanas.painelnfecomun.web.util.AutenticacaoFilter.doFilter(AutenticacaoFilter.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
>
```

However my application continue works.

Comment: Hi Sheep, did you resolve this? if so, how? thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the definitive answer without knowing more.

But bottom line is, something is writing to the response buffer, before setBufferSize is called. You need to identify what it is and invert that logic.

Just to clarify, if your authentication code is writing something as a response, like a redirect/forward, and you are calling chain.doFilter(request, response) after that, you will get that error, because doFilter is calling setBufferSize after you already wrote some response.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same topics (we moved to Apache Server, no topic there :) ), research in My Oracle Support:

Errors Found In OACORE Log 'Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Strict Servlet API: Cannot Call GetWriter() After User Cancels An LOV Action Within The Applications (Doc ID 2090612.1) :

**Summary:** Article suggests to IGNORE this message

How To Set Response Buffer Size On Webapp To Avoid java.lang.IllegalStateExecption: Response Already Committed (Doc ID 1520088.1)

**Summary:** Article suggests to write an own ResponseBufferFilter class and add it to web.xml